# How do I get rid of null values in my SQL results in java?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, arraylist, tostring

I am really struggling to resolve this issue please help me out if you can.

What this method does is, it retrieves the tags I have in my database by executing SQL query, storing the results in an ArrayList then return it.

My database contains 3 attributes : Name,Tag,Location. Where I just want to retrieve the tags and display them alone without showing the other attributes, so it would be like this format e.g [tag1,tag2,tag3]

And since the format in my toString method is like that and I can't change it to only be printing the tag because I have another method to display all these attributes together.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String p = (this.Name + ','+ this.Location+','+ this.Tag);

    return p;
}
```

I get null values for the other attributes when I chose to select only to output the tags and I get the result as follows : [null,null,rfid1, null,null,rfid2, null,null,rfid3]

So how do I get rid of these null values and only show tag bits ?

My method for getting tag values :

```
public ArrayList<wallet> getWalletTag() throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("----------------");
    System.out.println("Retrieve all tags");

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultset = null;     
    String query = "SELECT Tag FROM wallets;";

    ArrayList<wallet> WalletsList = new ArrayList<>();      
    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        System.out.println(query);
        resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);

        while (resultset.next()) {                  
            //String Name =  resultset.getString("Name");
            //String Loc =  resultset.getString("Location");
            String tag =  resultset.getString("Tag");

            WalletsList.add(new wallet (tag));
        }
    } 
    finally {

        if (resultset !=null){
            resultset.close();
        }
        if (statement !=null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (resultset !=null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
    return WalletsList;

}
```

my controller code :

```
    walletDAO dao2 = new walletDAO();


            ArrayList<wallet>  u ;

            try{

            u=dao2.getWalletTag();
```

Comment: thank you for trying to help, but I tried that already and didn't work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(Objects.nonNull(this.name)) {
        sb.append(this.name+",");
    }
    if(Objects.nonNull(this.location)) {
        sb.append(this.location+",");
    }
    if(Objects.nonNull(this.tag)) {
        sb.append(this.tag);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

This would help you i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Here just a short quick and dirty fix - surely there where nicer and more appropriate solutions... :)

```
    //quick and dirty fix
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      String NameHandle = "";
      String LocationHandle = "";

     if(this.Name!=null){NameHandle = this.Name + ",";}
     if(this.Location!=null){LocationHandle = this.Location+ ",";}

     String p = (this.Name + this.Location + this.Tag);

     return p;
     }
```